# Optimizing animations to show dozens or even hundreds on mobile in Unity

Tags: animation, optimization, mobile, unity-game-engine

Lately I've been working on making a castle-fight game in Unity. I've gotten some animated soldier models, and plan on having a few hundred in the scene. Problem is, on mobile I can't even display 50 at a time without having the FPS go below 20. I've already asked this question on Unity's forums, with no reply :(

Here's the link so you can see what I've done to optimize them so far: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/playing-hundreds-of-animations-on-mobile.444599/

I've never seen a game with dozens on animations on mobile. The closest I've seen is Fifa Mobile, but that's only about 20-30.

Do you think it's possible to optimize the animations more than I have (as shown in the link), or is it just impossible to have hundreds of animations on mobile?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: To improve the rendering speed you need to have optimised code tailored to your game. For that you need to write a game from scratch in a compiled language such as Java.

Comment: @Blindman67 creating a game in Java really isn't my thing. I'm simply quite surprised and disappointed that skinned mesh renderers are so hard on mobile, but I guess they are a bit complicated. Guess I'll have to try another project.

Comment: Gee skinned meshes. That is a lot to ask, try using static posed meshes. Should be able to take snapshots of the skinned meshes and then render them in sequence to animate. You should also test the limits of the device ,what is the max polycount at the frame rate you want, how much free GPU RAM is available to use, where is the bottleneck (GPU /CPU). Knowing that info will help you work out how to get past them. Don't be disappointed, I started on games when the home PC struggled to draw 4 two color sprites, but with some tricks a whole army could march down the screen. There is always a way.

Comment: There's no such think as a static posed mesh in Unity's "add component" menu, but it sounds like exactly what I need :(

Comment: I don't know what they would call it in unity. But it's just a mesh without animation, like a scenery object. If you can not get the snapshots via unity, do it on some other 3D editor.

Comment: Thanks, I've made some progress. I removed the skinned renderer and just added a regular mesh (like you'd put on a cube for instance). It shows, however it disappears during animation (probably because it can't change shape to fit the animation). When you say "get a snapshot", do you mean a screenshot, or something else? I have Blender, but animation really isn't my specialty. This project sure got a lot more interesting, I like it already! Once I get these "snapshots", "rendering them in sequence" is just showing them one after another? How is this more optimized than regular animations?

Comment: Yes snapshots of the skinned mesh, then play them one after another. Its more optimised as skinned meshes require a lot of processing power, both for the GPU and CPU, while static meshes require very little.

Comment: I could even go super cheap and make like 5-10 positions of the character, and then cycle them to create a choppy but moving effect. Perhaps that's what you mean by "snapshot"? I'm just confused as to if snapshot means a screenshot or the model stuck in position. It would be a very cheap, dirty and ugly method, but at the end of the day most Android devices are not known for speed.

Comment: 3D Model stuck in position.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, long story made short I re-partitioned my hard drive, screwed up and spent most of my developing time re-installing software and moving my files. Either way, I seem to have been able to put your idea into a working scene in Unity (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to @Blindman67 for giving me the general hang of things. With his help, I was able to create this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationConverter : MonoBehaviour {

//For example: Assets/_@MYSTUFF/StaticAnimations/
public string SaveLocation;
//Shows progress in inspector, useful if your animation is long
public string Progress;
public Animator MyAnimator;
//anim MUST be component of this.gameObject
public Animation anim;
public SkinnedMeshRenderer SkinMeshRender;
private Mesh[] NewStaticMesh;
//length of animation clip
private float ClipLenth;
//current animator int
private int CurrentAnimatorInt;
//just to make sure we run the code in Update ONCE
private bool AllowUpdate;
//how many frames do you want to make?
public int numberOfFrames;
//time between frame captures
private float WaitAmount;
//How many frames done
public int AmountSoFar;

private void Start()
{
    anim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
    AllowUpdate = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    //I'm getting an animation from my animator's current state
    CurrentAnimatorInt = MyAnimator.GetInteger("SoldierState");
    //checking to make sure we don't run more than once
    if (AllowUpdate == true)
    {
        if (CurrentAnimatorInt == 1)
        {
            //don't run this again
            AllowUpdate = false;
            //the magic begins!
            Debug.Log("Exporting static meshes from skinned mesh...");
            ExportMeshes();
        }
    }
}

void ExportMeshes()
{
    NewStaticMesh = new Mesh[numberOfFrames];
    ClipLenth = anim.clip.length;
    WaitAmount = anim.clip.length / numberOfFrames;
    //now let's start waiting for the animation to play
    StartCoroutine(WaitForNextMesh());
}

//IMPORTANT: We're using a coroutine because if we don't, we'll create
//the same static meshes because the animation won't change in 1 frame.
//The purpose is to wait as the animation is playing, then make a static mesh at the correct time.

IEnumerator WaitForNextMesh()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitAmount);
    AmountSoFar++;
    //wait done! Let's make the static mesh!
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    SkinMeshRender.BakeMesh(mesh);
    //show progress in inspector
    Progress = "Working... " + (AmountSoFar * 100 / numberOfFrames).ToString() + "%";
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(mesh, SaveLocation + AmountSoFar.ToString() + anim.clip.name + "_StaticFromSkinned" + ".asset");
    //do it again!
    if (AmountSoFar < numberOfFrames)
    {
        //do it again, we have more meshes to make!
        StartCoroutine(WaitForNextMesh());
    }

    else
    {
        //created all meshes, we're done!
        Progress = "All done! :)";
        //spam the console in fancy ways
        Debug.Log("<color=green><b>All meshes created! You'll find them here: </b></color>" + SaveLocation);
        Debug.Log("<color=red><i>Don't forget to disable/change this script, or you'll do what you just did again!</i></color>");
    }
}
}
```

It converts a skinned mesh to a series of static meshes. Then, I have this script to cycle thru those static meshes to make the animation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharachterAnimator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] Frames;
public int CurrentFrame;
public float TimeBetweenFrames;
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(GoToFrame());
}

IEnumerator GoToFrame()
{
    var wait = new WaitForSeconds(TimeBetweenFrames);
    while (true)
    {
        Frames[CurrentFrame].SetActive(true);
        yield return wait;
        Frames[CurrentFrame].SetActive(false);
        CurrentFrame++;
        if (CurrentFrame < Frames.Length)
        {
            Frames[CurrentFrame].SetActive(true);
        }

        else
        {
            CurrentFrame = 0;
            Frames[0].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I added hundreds of soldiers to my scene, and Camera.Render takes most of the resources in the Profiler, so I can confidently say that while this method makes the animations look jerky, after all I'm targeting Android devices (some of which are slower than a potato). The performance improvement is giant, and I should be able to get a few hundred of these characters going if I optimize Camera.Render (lighting, shadows etc... in Unity).

Once again, huge thanks to @Blindman67 for the idea that I was able to execute.